C# Json Deserialized objects in custom class, to be used in foreach loops, requires IEnumerable
I am loading a custom Json into a custom getter/setter class, however I am completely inexperienced with IEnumerables, and getting a bit stuck.
{ 
 "Item1": {"a": value, "b": value, "c": []},
}

In the future, it may contain more than one Item#, but it will always have A B and C in that standard.
Using NewtonSoft Json package, I am doing a
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigurationFile>(jsonConfig)

The ConfigurationFile class is my own one, which looks like this:
public class ConfigurationFile
{
    public ItemInfo? item{ get; set; }
}

public class ItemInfo
{
    public string a{ get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string[]? c { get; set; }
}

Here is where the issue is. All the items are setting properly, as expected. But in preparation for future, I need to read and do something with each Item's A, B, or C.
The error I am getting, is that if I start a
foreach (ConfigurationFile item in loadedJson)
{
  // ...do something to item.a
}

Then I get an error of ConfigurationFile class can only be used in foreach if it implements IEnumerate or IEnumerate, or a suitable GetEnumerator method.
What is the mistake I am making? The only guess I can hazard, is that my custom class for get/set would only really work for 1 item, and thus, cannot be part of a for-each statement... but I am not sure how to go about working that out.

public ItemInfo? item{ get; set; } should be item1 not item with your existing JSON. But I suspect your issue is that later you want to add Item2, Item3 etc etc and not change your SQL code. If that is the case, don't put item1 in the JSON at all - put an array there instead.

So, would creating an array out of items be the way to go then? something akin to {"Items":[ "Item1: { "a":"value,"b":"value","c":[]}, "Item2: { "a":"value,"b":"value","c":[]}, ]. Unless I am misunderstanding

Something like: {"Items":[ { "Name": "Item1", "a":"value,"b":"value","c":[]}, { "Name": "Item2", "a":"value,"b":"value","c":[]}, ]

First of all, JSON uses double quotes ", so your JSON should look like this:
{ 
    "Item1": {"a": "value", "b": "value", "c": []}
}

For simplicity I assume that array stored in c will be simple array of strings, eg.: "c": ["value1", "value2"]
So we can model the object as:
public class Model
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    public string[] c { get; set; }
}

Then, in JSON pair "key": "value" is key and value pair as in dictionary, thus, your JSON can be treated as dictionary. Putting it all together, here's code snippet with working deserialization:
var rawJson = @"{ 
    ""Item1"": {""a"": ""value"", ""b"": ""value"", ""c"": []}
}";

var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Model>>(rawJson);

